# Injection error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a module in separate file :

```
(function () {
var staffGrid = angular.module('staffGrid');
staffGrid.directive('employee2', function () {
        return {
            restrict:'E',
            template:"Tralala2"};
    });
})
```

In main JS file I add dependency:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('teamStaffApp', ['staffGrid' ]);
```

In HTML (staffGrid.js has been loaded( checked)):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/staffGrid.js"></script>
```

And have got the error :
    https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=teamStaffApp&p1=undefined

What is wrong? I am stuck
Without injection staffGrid - all works

Answer (score 0):

To declare new module `staffGrid` you need to provide a dependencies array as the second parameter, otherwise it's a getter syntax:

```
var staffGrid = angular.module('staffGrid', []);
```

Comment: It does not work even with []. I removed it trying all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
(function () {
    var staffGrid = angular.module('staffGrid', []); // [] has to be passed here
        staffGrid.directive('employee2', function () {
            return {
                restrict:'E',
               template:"Tralala2"};
       });
})(); // <-----missed this ();
```